# overlaying location map (coastline) on slice plots in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I made plots of depth slices using function slice, with each slice showing earth's velocity distribution. I am having a hard time overlaying the location map (coastline) on the figure. Does anyone know if this is possible with MatLab? OR Can you overlay any x,y(and z) plot on slice image?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Post some of the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: Can you post some examples. Its extremely difficul to understand what you mean.

Comment: slice3d is not a Matlab function, isn't it?

Comment: @ Trilarion: Sorry, I meant the slice function (not slice3d)

Comment: %Plotting for 3D_Slices 1 and 2
lat = 44:.5:52; lon = 292:.5:305;
Z = -20:.5:0;
depth = Z';
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(lon,lat,depth);
xslice = [305.2];
yslice = [52.1];
zslice = [-20,-15,-10,-5,0];
h=slice(x,y,z,V,xslice,yslice,zslice);
set(h,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp','FaceAlpha','interp')
alpha('color')
alphamap('rampdown')
alphamap('increase',.05)
caxis([2.9,3.84]);
colorbar('vertical');
ylim([43.99,52.01]);
xlim([291.99, 305.01]);
zlim([-20.01,0]);lon = 292:.5:305;

The figure is similar to: http://blog.philippklaus.de/2012/10/creating-a-gaussian-window-in-3d-using-matlab/

Comment: I could not overlay the location map (coastline) and some x-y plot on the slice figure. Hold on and off does not seem to work for me. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I figured it out. Had to import coastline data from some online database and used hold on/off to overlay, with plot3. My original plan of using the mapping tools on MatLab didn't work.